# IPTables won't start automatically after reboot - Red Hat 7

Tags: centos, redhat, systemctl

In Red Hat 7 I'm trying to force the IP tables service to start automatically after reboot. Currently, after every reboot I need to run the command:

`sudo systemctl start iptables`

I've tried setting

`sudo chkconfig iptables on`

but it isn't running.

In my file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` I've set

`IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP="yes"
 IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="yes"`

Can someone let me know how to set this to start on reboot?

Comment: You need to sit down with the documentation, things have moved on in the RHEL firewall world.

Comment: `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http --permanent` and `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=https --permanent` and then `firewall-cmd --reload`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per RHEL7/Centos7 there is no iptables service available in the default install. Instead they want you to use `firewalld` which is turned on by default. (see `man firewall-cmd` for more information on how to operate firewalld )

If you want to use iptables u need to install `iptables-services` and enable them with `systemctl enable iptables`. You will need to turn off firewalld with `systemctl disable firewalld`.

If there isn't a really specific reason to use iptables or chkconfig I would advise you not use them. Instead I would invest in learning how firewalld and systemctl works.

Answer (score 0):

Rules created with the iptables command are stored in memory. If the system is restarted before saving the iptables rule set, all rules are lost. For netfilter rules to persist through a system reboot, they need to be saved first.

To save rules, type the following command as root:

```
iptables-save
```

or

```
service iptables save
```

After this restart the iptables service.

```
service iptables restart
```

You can modify the service commands to start or stop service as per your flavour of linux.

Comment: That didn't work. I still need to run the command every time that I restart.

Comment: Indeed, the files `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (and `/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables`) to which should be written by the commands above (though not as given: the commands write to stdout, so you really would have to do `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`) are not read on boot. Time for `firewalld` then.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

## Install iptables services (since CentOS 7 the default firewall is firewalld, so we have to install the iptables service ourselves)

yum -y install iptables-services;

## Disable firewalld service (which is the default in CentOS 7)

systemctl disable firewalld;

## Mask firewalld service (to prevent SysOp from accidently starting the service)

systemctl mask firewalld;

## Start iptables

service iptables restart;

## Save iptables rules to disk so that after reboot these rules will be applied

service iptables save;

Comment: Write more it works and what it does. You could split the command into new lines, instead of this semicolon-separated ultralong line. There is a vote about your answer, if it loses, it will be deleted.